# fatal: bad boolean config value 'origin' for 'push.autosetupremote'

Tags: git, github, terminal

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NUm3.png)
When trying to git push, to send the project to github, it does not allow saying: fatal: bad boolean config value 'origin' for 'push.autosetupremote'.

I’ve tried Remove Incorrect Setting: `git config --unset push.autosetupremote`

Remove Existing Remote Config: `git remote remove origin` and add `git remote add origin https://github.com/NatalyeCavalieri/NodeMovie.git`

Comment: I guess you figured out your own answer, but next time please don't include screen shots of terminal logs, cut and paste them as code blocks.

Answer (score -1):

```
git config --global --unset-all push.autosetupremote

git config --global push.autosetupremote true **or** false
```